# How do I set ViewBag properties on _ViewStart.cshtml?

Tags: razor

I have a specific ViewBag property that I would like to set at the ViewStart level.  Ideally, I would like to be able to override that property on a page basis, if necessary.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I access the ViewBag property within a ViewStart page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two way to do this:

1. Use the `PageData` property (it's something more applicable to ASP.NET WebPages and seldom used in MVC)

   - Set:

     ```
     @{
         PageData["message"] = "Hello";
     }
     ```
   - Retrieve

     ```
     <h2>@PageData["message"]</h2>
     ```
2. Try to find the view instance (the code is a bit dirty, but it does give you access directly to `ViewBag`/`ViewData`

   - Set:

     ```
     @{
         var c = this.ChildPage;
         while (c != null) {
             var vp = c as WebViewPage;
             if (vp != null) {
                 vp.ViewBag.Message = "Hello1";
                 break;
             }
             c = c.ChildPage;
         }
     }
     ```
   - Retrieve: as per usual

     ```
     <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
     ```

Comment: That's unfortunate.  An action filter doesn't make sense for my situation.  I wanted to set a property that tells the layout which menu is active.  I guess I'll just add the property to each page.

Comment: @Jim I was too quick. See revised answer.

Comment: ViewPage is analogous to SessionVar that's sticky to the page instead of session?

Comment: More like request context items, but sure it's specific to the view page hierarchy.

Comment: #2 is an interesting solution... it does feel really dirty, but would get the job done.  Maybe I could wrap that in an extension method to make me feel better about it.  :)

Comment: Doesn't work, I get an error:  'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase' does not contain a definition for 'ChildPage' and no extension method 'ChildPage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I am also experiencing PsychoDad's problem, ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta

Comment: For mvc3 fit `ViewContext.Controller.ViewData("Title") = "My title"`

Comment: @jjxtra - I was able to get method 2 working by changing `while` to `if` and removing `c = c.ChildPage;` and `break;`  Thanks @marcind!