# Why can't _ViewStart.cshtml access the ViewBag object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the default _ViewStart.cshtml in my /Views folder.  I'd like to be able to access my ViewBag object so I can set the default title for all my views.

However, with:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "bytecourse - Online Courses in Technology";
}
```

I get "The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context" as a runtime error.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In short...  Use the controller's view bag.

```
ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.MyVar = "myVal";
```

and

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.MyVar
```

===============================================================

There is good information here: http://forums.asp.net/post/4254825.aspx

===============================================================

> Generally, ViewData["StoreName"] is same as ViewBag.StoreName
>
> Also, Controller.ViewData["StoreName"] = Controller.StoreName =
>   ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.StoreName
>   =ViewContext.Controller.ViewData["StoreName"]
>
> But every view and partial view gets its own instance of viewdata.
>
> http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/viewdata-mechanics-and-segmentation-excerpt-from-asp.net-mvc-in-action/

===============================================================

There is a another solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834382/291753

===============================================================

Answer (score 4):

hmm, you can access ViewBag via ViewData, e.g. `ViewContext.ViewData["Title"]`.

So if you set ViewBag data in an action filter for example, you can pull it out from _ViewStart.cshtml using `ViewContext.ViewData["Title"]`.

But I tried to assign a value using `ViewContext.ViewData["Key"] = value;` and it doesn't seem to persist to the actual view.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using Partial views. Put all your Title related common code in a Partial View called `Title.cshtml` in the shared folder. In the `_viewstart` simply call the Partial view.

**_ViewStart.cshtml**:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.Partial("Title")
```

**~/Shared/Title.cshtml**:

```
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "bytecourse - Online Courses in Technology"; 
}
```

Comment: In my mvc5 project, ViewBag values which has been from partial view is not accessible from main view. Same problem with ViewData

Even if I render my partial directly into layout page

Answer (score 3):

You could use sections in your _Layout if you want to set a default title:

```
<title>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Title"))
    {
        @RenderSection("Title")
    }
    else
    {
        @:bytecourse - Online Courses in Technology
    }
</title>
```

and inside views you could override it:

```
@section Title {
    Overriden title
}
```

One more reason not to use `ViewBag` :-)

Comment: Hi @Darin Dimitrov, is not used `@RenderSection("Title")` is used `@RenderSection("Title", required:=false)` in case of, do you have a need requirement IsSectionDefined("Title") ??

Comment: @BeratBilgin it depends if you want a default value or not if that section is not defined by the view.

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100% clean but see a workaround using PageData or a bit of enumeration at:

[How do I set ViewBag properties on _ViewStart.cshtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834045/how-do-i-set-viewbag-properties-on-viewstart-cshtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can create one layout page which is using your Viewbag data and add layout to your blank _ViewStart page it will work

on ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```