# ِِHow to Access the viewbag in the _viewstart.chtml in mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to change the layout according the user in the _viewstart.chtml . I have seen the answers in the question [Why can't _ViewStart.cshtml access the ViewBag object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578029/why-cant-viewstart-cshtml-access-the-viewbag-object) and the answers suggests to use   ViewContext.ViewBag but in mvc 5 i have the error

```
An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property
```

So how i can use the viewbag or ViewContext in _viewstart.chtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will compile and there's no error in the runtime despite there being an error in the _viewstart code

[image]