# Razor template variable scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, template-engine

Are variables I define in a shared layout `_Layout.cshtml` within scope of a View page?

**_Layout.cshtml varibles:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.url = "http://www.website.com/site/";
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<a class="continue" href="@ViewBag.url/our-vision/">Continue</a>
```

This outputs: `/our-vision/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try answer from this question: [How do I set ViewBag properties on _ViewStart.cshtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834045/how-do-i-set-viewbag-properties-on-viewstart-cshtml)

Set (Note: code is for _ViewStart, not for _Layout)

```
@{
    PageData["message"] = "Hello";
}
```

Get

```
<h2>@PageData["message"]</h2>
```

OR

Create more interesting solution: [How to set ViewBag properties for all Views without using a base class for Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453327/how-to-set-viewbag-properties-for-all-views-without-using-a-base-class-for-contr)

Comment: That worked but do you know why he says that PageData is seldom used in MVC?

Comment: @CharliePrynn `PageData` provides array-like access to page data that is shared between pages, layout pages, and partial pages. You can't access it from controller. Usually developers path data from controller using `ViewData` to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:
ViewBag is different for each view/layout and razor renders view firstly and it's layout afterwards.

Solution for this issue could be setting common constant in base controller orview or global filter instead of layout.