# add logic to _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

is there a way to add logic in the _ViewStart.cshtml file to drive which _Layout file to use?

Conceptually, I want to do the code below (ViewBag.Context is determined in the Home controller). But I get a red squiggly under ViewBag (does not exist in current context). I guess this is a problem because this view page doesn't know which controller/method is calling it.

```
@{if (ViewBag.Context == "AA")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_AA.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of you are not seeing "But I get a red squiggly under ViewBag (does not exist in current context). I guess this is a problem because this view page doesn't know which controller/method is calling it."

My solution was to embed the value in a cookie while in the controller at the start. Then in the _ViewStart.cshtml file, I retrieve the cookie value and can now use it to dictate my layout logic.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can also do this in the controller:

```
if (someCondition == "AA")
{
    return View("MyView", "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_AA.cshtml");
}
else
{
    return View ("MyView", "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PageData property (it's something more applicable to ASP.NET WebPages and seldom used in MVC)
Set:

```
@{
    PageData["message"] = "Hello";
}
```

Retrieve

```
<h2>@PageData["message"]</h2>
```

Source: [How do I set ViewBag properties on _ViewStart.cshtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834045/how-do-i-set-viewbag-properties-on-viewstart-cshtml/4834382#4834382)

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator:

```
@{
   Layout = ViewBag.Context == "AA" ? "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_AA.cshtml" : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" ;
  }
```